# Android canvas clip Mask using path

Tags: android, android-canvas

I need to draw this:

[image: result]

and this:
[image]

Can i make object and rotate it from point with x y cord and length + angle (vector)?

But i can't understand how to make a clip mask for canvas using Path.

```
red.setColor(0xff033cd0);
        red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        path.reset();
        path = new Path();
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(boxWTstopX, boxWTstartY);
        path.lineTo(boxWTstartX, boxWTstartY);
       // path.moveTo(point2_returned.x, point2_returned.y);
        path.lineTo(boxWTstartX, boxWTstopY);
        path.lineTo(boxWTstopX, boxWTstartY);
        //path.moveTo(point3_returned.x, point3_returned.y);
       // path.lineTo(point1_returned.x, point1_returned.y);
        path.close();

        //canvas.drawPath(path, red);
        canvas.clipPath(path);
```

But after that i drawing on Retrangle region... How i do that? i have no idea.

**P.S**:

I have no idea why i cant make object retrangle with lenght 100 and width 200 and than print it from cords! It will be more "friendly" than 2 points... is it posible?

Maybe there is a way to make object (contains: paths + rects + etc) and than print it from x y cords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i make object and rotate it from point with x y cord and length +
>   angle (vector)?

Well, you can. But instead of rotating the *object*, you could rotate the canvas in increments and then draw. So what you need to do is use `canvas.rotate()`. Your requirement sounds a lot like the *drawing the pointers of Meter guage* that I worked on. You can refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33606134/4747587. This will give you an idea on how to draw by rotating the `canvas`.

> But i can't understand how to make a clip mask for canvas using Path.

You use `clipPath` to perform a sort of Masking. How you do that? Well refer to this: [How to Clip a Star in android ? But the appearance of the star is clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301655/how-to-clip-a-star-in-android-but-the-appearance-of-the-star-is-clear). The code in the question will let you know how to use `clipPath`. But you can't get `ANTI-ALIAS` in this. If you want that, go through the answer to perform `Bitmap Masking`.

Comment: Thak you ill try this! \0/

Comment: Now i have an arc, and use it like progress bar. But there are one problem...
When val is rising by 1, it grows 1 degree.. it's a very big step. 

How i can move it slowly by 1/2 of degree or 1/4?

Comment: `Canvas.rotate(float degree, float x, float y)` : So you can increment the `degree` by 0.25 or 0.5 based on your need. That should work.

Comment: And there are no way to use float in DrawArc method? So when i try to add float degree1 = 123.02 studio show error that is double, not float.... so any way ill try both again.

Comment: Yes by default `123.02` is considered `double`. Instead, use `float degree1 = 123.02f`. This is how you define floating number.